# How to use Objective-C bridging header in a Swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I've been asked to use a Objective-C framework in my Swift project.

But I have no idea how to accomplish this.

I've added this file:

```
Objective-CBridgingHeader.h
```

Inside this file I've put:

```
#ifndef Objective_CBridgingHeader_h
#define Objective_CBridgingHeader_h

#import <FMShop/FMShop.h>

#endif /* Objective_CBridgingHeader_h */
```

Now I was expecting to be able to:

```
Import FMShop
```

And get access to that framework using Swift code. 
However when I try to

```
Import FMShop
```

My project no longer compiles claiming that there: 
"No such module 'FMShop'"

What am I missing here?

My base SDK is iOS 8.0 and I'm using Xcode 7.3.1

This is what my project looks like:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call Objective-C code from Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a new Objective-C file to your Xcode project.  Name it as you please and you should get an alert box asking if you would like to create a bridging header. Then delete that file as it was just used to create Bridging Header.

[image]

Alternatively you can you can create a bridging header yourself by choosing File > New > File > (iOS, watchOS, tvOS, or macOS) > Source > Header File. Name the file as "ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h" e.g. if Project Name is Test then give file name as "Test-Bridging-Header.h".

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Answer (score 1):

Go to build settings and search for Objective-C Bridging Header key and provide path of your bridging header file.In my case it is "Main/Main-Bridging-Header.h".

Comment: I've done that without rename the file. Does renaming the file really matter?